# What do air traffic controllers call themselves? Or how are ATCs referred? "Controller"? "ATC"? "Control"?

Tags: air-traffic-control, terminology

What do air traffic controllers call themselves? Or how are ATCs referred? Is it "controller"? "ATC"? "Control"? For example, if I wanted to say an airport has a shortage of air traffic controllers or if I wished to say there was a group consisting of pilots and air traffic controllers, but don't want to use the entire phrase, what can I use instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Most call their peers controllers. If you get a bunch of Type A people working next to each other, conflict sometimes arises, and their peer references can get a bit more colorful!

Answer (score 0):

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_traffic_controller) on ATCOs:

> Although the media in the United States frequently refers to them as
> air controllers, or flight controllers, most air traffic professionals
> use the term air traffic controllers, ATCOs, or controllers.

In my (limited) personal experience, ATCO seems to be popular in the UK.